# What's the preferred way to return an empty table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I know I can return an empty table using the following query :

```
select * from tbFoo where 1=2
```

but that code doesn't look nice to me.

**Is there a 'standard' way of doing this?**

If you're wondering why I want to do such a strange thing, it's because [I can't name the datatables I return from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589976/how-can-you-name-the-datasets-tables-you-return-in-a-stored-proc), so I need empty placeholders.

Comment: Are you trying to populate a DataTable from a Stored Procedure?

Comment: select * from tbFoo where 1=2 is what I've used in the past. Not sure if its a "standard" way but I've used it many times and seen it used by others.

Comment: @REA_ANDREW : the fact that I intend to use this empty data as a return resultset from a stored procedure doesn't mean I don't know how to handle a resultset in c#. I suggest you delete your off-topic answer:)

Comment: I have deleted. :)  I misunderstood both your question and your response!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Having just run both:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM Table
and
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1=0
```

They produce exactly the same execution plan.

Comment: @GateKiller : this looks better :)

Comment: what about select top 0 1 from Table ?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I see 1=0 but yes thats pretty much the standard approach when you really have to.  Although really having to is rare.

Comment: Ok. Are there any performances implication depending on the table I choose for my select? I guess not...

Comment: I doubt there is any big performance issue, the optimizer is going to see that there is no need to read anything from the DB, take a look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is `information_schema`, using it will allow you to find out the definition of a table.

You don't mention which database you are using, so here is a link about [`information_schema` Support in MySQL, PostgreSQL](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/666.cfm) (and MSSQL, Oracle, Etc)

An example from the site;

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, is_nullable, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE table_name = 'employees'
```

In your case, all you need are the column names;

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE table_name = 'employees'
```