# stubborn error when trying to merge a table into a dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I'm trying to track down a .NET error in my little game here.

Here is the error:

> ArgumentNullException: 'table' argument cannot be null
>
> System.DataSet.Merge(DattaTable table)

It's occurring on the line below where it tries to merge a table into an existing dataset.

I'm trying to do as many checks as I think I can to determine if the dataset or table are empty, but it continues to error on the ds.Merge line.

```
Dim ds As DataSet
'getData = simple function that uses SqlConnection & SqlDataAdapter to get data from my database
ds = utils.getData("Sproc_GetGameEncounters")

Dim MonsterDataSet As DataSet

MonsterDataSet = utils.getData("Sproc_MonsterDataSetFromDB")

If Not MonsterDataSet Is Nothing Then
    If MonsterDataSet.Tables("TreasureList") Is Nothing OrElse MonsterDataSet.Tables("TreasureList").Rows.Count = 0 Then
        'MonsterDataSet.Tables("TreasureList") is  empty
    Else
        ds.Merge(MonsterDataSet.Tables("TreasureList"))  'line where error occurs
    End If
End If
```

Are there more checks I could add to help fix or at least track down this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Use debugger to ensure a table exists named TreasureList in MonsterDataSet.

Comment: `Dim MonsterDataSet As DataSet` does not create a DataSet, it simply declares an object variable.  Unless `utils.getData` returns a DataSet (not DataTable) it will be Nothing. That seems like it would result in an NRE though.  So whatever that mysterious helper does, it does not create a table by that name in that dataset...at least not always.  That code doesnt show any of those things being created

Comment: Seems like that "helper" method is less helpful (or less smart) than it could be.  If it returned a DataTable, rather than 2 DataSets, you could simply add each table to a single dataset when you call it.

Comment: Is there multithreading involved?

Comment: Hi @Minh, how would I determine that?  There are multiple players for this game...

Comment: The problem seems to be that MonsterDataSet.Tables("TreasureList") has some value at one instance and null the next. This can happen because of race conditions. Can the players modify the TreasureList?

Comment: @Minh yes they can...

Comment: More than likely. the table created is not named.  Since the "helper"  isnt told the TableName, it most likely doesnt have one.  Ergo `dsMosnter.Tables("anything")` will return null.  It only takes 3 lines of code to create a DataTable in a DataSet, so it is not clear why `getData` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. The problem is the adapter, it not get the names of tables. I have a similar function and I'm happy to share it.

You can set the table name after dataset filled, or with `TableMappings` ([here an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589976/how-can-you-name-the-datasets-tables-you-return-in-a-stored-proc) for `TableMappings`), but I preferred the first way.

**Function to fill the dataset**

```
    Private Function sql_fillDataset(sql As String, Optional tablesName As String() = Nothing) As DataSet


        dim sql_connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds = New DataSet

        Try

            sql_connection = New SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING")
            sql_connection.Open()

            command = New SqlCommand(sql, sql_connection)

            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds)

            If Not tablesName Is Nothing AndAlso Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso Not ds.Tables Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count = tablesName.Length Then
                For i = 0 To ds.Tables.Count - 1
                    ds.Tables(i).TableName = tablesName(i)
                Next
            End If

            command.Dispose()
            adapter.Dispose()
            sql_connection.Close()
            sql_connection.Dispose()

            Return ds
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
```

**How to use it**

```
Dim ds As New Dataset
ds = sql_fillDataset("SELECT * FROM TABLE1")
' #### Here is your case, and you haven't the table name
ds.tables(0)
```

Or

```
Dim ds As New Dataset
ds = sql_fillDataset("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", New String() {"TABLE1"})
' #### Here is your solution, but the dataset have the name !!
ds.tables("TABLE1")
```

Or with more than one tables

```
Dim ds As New Dataset
ds = sql_fillDataset("SELECT * FROM TABLE1; SELECT * FROM TABLE2", New String() {"TABLE1", "TABLE2"})
ds.tables("TABLE1")
ds.tables("TABLE2")
```

Hope this help you.